# Qt: QObject::connect: No such slot

Tags: c++11, qt5, ros, signals-slots, qpushbutton

I am building a small interface where I subclassed `RViz` which is a visualizer from [ROS](http://www.ros.org/). According to the [official documentation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rviz/html/c++/classrviz_1_1ViewManager.html#a2f029f5bc775b8e211b9254b1bd36bc8) it is possible to re-use and re-implement some of the functions present in this tool. What I am trying to do is creating two different `QPushButton` that will chnage the view of the renderer implemented. 
I have some problems with the `SIGNAL` ans `SLOT` for my two buttons, in fact as I click them, the view doesn't change. 
Now `RViz` has a specific function called `getNumViews()` that allows the user to set the number of views. In my case I have two views only related to the two `QPushButton` I am implementing.

[image: sig-slot]

As I run the application program I receive the following error `QObject::connect: No such slot MyViz::switchToView()` and thought that all the passages to correctly set the `SIGNALS` and `SLOT` were correctly according to the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). Also for completeness I am using `C++11` and from researching more I found that the old [version](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/signalsandslots.html) of the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT`, which is the one I am using is supposed to be still valid.

Below the code related to the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` that I am running:

**myviz.h**

```
public Q_SLOTS:
    void switchToView(QString view);

private:
    rviz::ViewManager *view_man;
```

**myviz.cpp**

```
MyViz::MyViz(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

// operation in the constructor

    QPushButton *topViewBtn = new QPushButton("Top View");
    QPushButton *sideViewBtn = new QPushButton("Side View");


    connect(topViewBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(switchToView(QString("Top View"))));
    connect(sideViewBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(switchToView(QString("Side View"))));

}
```

here is where I set the 2 views possibilities related to the two `QPushButtons`

```
void MyViz::switchToView(QString view)
{
    view_man = manager->getViewManager();
    for(int i = 0; i<view_man->getNumViews(); i++)
    {
        if(view_man->getViewAt(i)->getName() == view)
            view_man->setCurrentFrom(view_man->getViewAt(i));
                    return;
        std::cout<<"Did not find view named %s"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Thank you for pointing in the right direction for solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass arguments in the connect function using the old syntax. Also the number and type of arguments need to match, so you can only connect `clicked` to functions without arguments. If you want to use the old syntax, you need to define 2 slots

```
public Q_SLOTS:
    void switchToTopView();
    void switchToSideView();
```

which you can then connect via:

```
connect(topViewBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(switchToTopView()));
connect(sideViewBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(switchToSideView()));
```

edit:

The correct syntax for new connect method is:

```
connect( topViewBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyViz::switchToTopView);
```

The advantage of this method is that you can also bind to lambdas, which indirectly lets you set parameters during connect, so you could write

```
connect( topViewBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){
    switchToView( QString("Top View") );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Thomas. Could you update your answer also in case I will need to use the new notation please?